# PHP CURL timing out?

Tags: php, curl

This times out every time. How to fix it?

```
<?
$curl = curl_init("https://gstdealerdaily.fitsvcs.com/siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $result;
```

Comment: That URL times out for me...try a diffrent one

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more cURL functions in order to work.

```
<?php
$target_url="https://gstdealerdaily.fitsvcs.com/siteminderagent/forms/login.fcc";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,4); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$html = curl_exec($ch);

$html = preg_replace("#(<\s*a\s+[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"'])(?!http)([^\"'>]+)  ([\"'>]+)#",'$1'.$target_url.'$2$3', $html);
echo $html;

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Dumped curl errors and I get: Curl error: connect() timed out!

Comment: are you sure cURL is enabled and running in you server? @user1724365